# cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (3)

Tags: reshape

```
x_dataset=[]
y_dataset=[]
src=os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Betel_leaf/dataset/training_set/healthy_leaf')
i=0
for filename in src:
    full_file_name='/content/drive/MyDrive/Betel_leaf/dataset/training_set/healthy_leaf'+filename
    x=cv2.imread(full_file_name)
    x=np.array(x,dtype='float32')
    y=0
    y=np.array(y,dtype='float32')
    x= stats.zscore(x.reshape(-1, 3)).reshape(x.shape)
    x=cv2.resize(x,(224,224))
    x_dataset.append(x)
    y_dataset.append(y)
    i=i+1
    print(i)
```

Error:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-59-3be09956b881> in <module>
      9     y=0
     10     y=np.array(y,dtype='float32')
---> 11     x= stats.zscore(x.reshape(-1, 3)).reshape(x.shape)
     12     x=cv2.resize(x,(224,2224))
     13     x_dataset.append(x)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (3)
```

I have 400 images in my dataset. Why the array size is showing 1 here? Please help me out. I need to use InceptionV3 model later.

Comment: expend line 11 `z = x.reshape(-1, 3)` , `z = stats.zscore(z)`, `x = z.reshape(x.shape)` to understand which one stops code. then use `print(x.shape)` between each steps to debug your code.

Comment: z = x.reshape(-1, 3)              this line is showing same error

Comment: What does `print(x.shape)` show if you put it before error line?

Comment: You have to check if x is the image you expect. if the directory of image be wrong, `cv2.imread` doesn't throw any error and returns `Nonetype` I think.